# I can't load my web application into a webview

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview

I've developed my own jQuery mobile project and host it on a website, it is available here:

http://thecoffeedrinker.site11.com/Youtube%20Theater/home.html

I can use this app from my mobile browser; now I would like to wrap it into an Android Application to publish it on Google Play. So I built a simple activity consisting into a webview, where I load the url:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_theater_wrapper);
    WebView appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pageView);
    WebSettings webSettings = appView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    appView.loadUrl("http://thecoffeedrinker.site11.com/Youtube%20Theater/home.html");
}
```

The problem is that the page is never displayed. All I get is the jQuery Mobile undefined progress bar, just like the loading is taking forever.

Is there any way to display the pages properly?

Comment: Did you add the permission in the manifest to connect to internet - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ?

Comment: yes of course, if the website is for instance www.google.com it works

Comment: What are you testing on and does it work in the native browser on that device?

Comment: If I use the native browser I can access that website. Now I would like an app to wrap it.

Comment: @DharmaDude added an answer, hope it solves it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your webView:

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

So:

```
WebView appView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pageView);
WebSettings webSettings = appView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
appView.loadUrl("http://thecoffeedrinker.site11.com/Youtube%20Theater/home.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this into your java file

```
    appView.loadUrl("http://thecoffeedrinker.site11.com/Youtube%20Theater/home.html");
    appView.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 100000);
```

Comment: The webview doesn't have any method "setIntegerProperty"

Comment: try super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 100000);